# Mockito issues when running a Play app in development mode

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework, mockito, playframework-1.x

I am writing unit tests for a Play 1.x app, and using Mockito to easily create mock instances on the fly. I am running in development mode, so that I don't have to restart the app frequently.

The problem comes when I change the code, and the re-run my unit tests without restarting the Play app. I get the following exception:

```
A java.lang.ClassCastException has been caught, Cannot cast services.MyService$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$12cee5a2 to services.MyService
```

When I restart te app, and re-run the tests, all of them execute fine, but it takes me up to a couple of minutes to restart every time. Is there something that could be done?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem when working with Play, the lib classloader stays the same while the developed code is being changed on each reload, which causes *issues* for libraries that cache reflection related things, there a *CCE*.

You have to disable the class cache by overriding the default configuration, see the complete [documentation](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/configuration/IMockitoConfiguration.html).

The idea is that in your test code base, create a class with the following qualified name `org.mockito.configuration.MockitoConfiguration` that will extends `org.mockito.configuration.DefaultMockitoConfiguration` and override the method `boolean enableClassClache()` to return false.

Comment: I must be using a crazy old version of Mockito, because the enableClassCache() method is not present in the IMockitoConfiguration interface. I will try to update and do what you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: I implemented the said method, and I believe that this should solve my problems. Yet, I can't find a way to load this class through Play's class loader. I believe that I have to place the compiled class file somewhere for it to be picked up by Mockito. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You may have to make dummy dependency for play to declare in the test classpath. Sorry I cannot really help you more than that as I don't know play 1.x